# What is the probability of a football team qualifying from a round robin format competition?

Tags: probability

This question has many facets as there are quite a few variables, so I will make it as simple as possible.

**CONCACAF**

**1. A ten team round robin with four automatic qualifying spaces and the 5th place team is entered into a two legged play off. Each team plays twice, home and away a total of 18 games.**

Question A: what is the probability of a top ranked team to qualify directly in any of the four available automatic spaces, where there is only two other teams at the same level and the rest of them are weaker sides.

**Europe**

**2. An eight team round robin, with one automatic qualification space and the second place team is entered into a two legged play off. Each team play a total of 12 games home and away.**

Question B. What is the probability of a top ranked team qualifying automatically where there is only one other top team in the group and the rest are weaker sides?

Comment: You should restrict yourself to one question. Also show the effort you have put in

Comment: It is actually the same question as I want to see which one is harder

Comment: I also don't know anything about Math.